# Program runs slow after boot in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot

I have a PC installed with Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.4.0-42-generic.

When I run a test program that computes a square matrix product, the program takes aound 100 seconds to complete. I takes around the same time to execute if I run again several time the
same program. But If I start another program like Chrome and then I run the same program it takes around 50 seconds to execute.
I have run the perf tool on this program and it shows :

- 100 seconds : 430 10^9 cpu-cycles, around 0.09 instructions / cycle
  and 418 10^9 stalled-cycles-backend
- 50 seconds : 220 0^9 cpu-cycles, around 0.18 instructions / cycle
  and 211 10^9 stalled-cycles-backend

Does anybody have an idea where does the problem come from, or any hint to help me find the cause of the problem ?

Best regards
JM

Comment: What are you using to run the code - Matlab, Octave, custom C code, bash script? What is the actual problem in your opinion, that the code takes that long, or that it appears to run faster when opening another application?

Answer (score 0):

Linux propably uses the powersave mode for the CPU (frequency goes only up, if xour CPU usage is high). You can use a `cpupower` to change it. (The CPU will use more Energy and Laptops will have shorter battery life)